# requests + VK API: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', ...)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests

Пишу бота в вк, делаю в нем get-запрос, который при нажатии на кнопку в ЛС с ботом качает с сайта pdf-файл и сохраняет на комп, а затем отправляет фотографию этого pdf-а в личные сообщения. Проблема в том, что после запуска бота в первые 5-7 минут всё работает исправно, но затем, при очередном нажатии на кнопку в диалоге с ботом, вылазит ошибка библиотеки requests:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 
'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

Вот так выглядит мой get-запрос:

```
    headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 
    Firefox/66.0",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "cookie": "sp_test=1",}}
    url = "(тут мой url)"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Насколько я понимаю, такая ошибка происходит из-за того, что сайт считает меня ботом, а не человеком, и прерывает соединение со мной

Comment: Зачем писать такой юзерагент? всегда пишу честно "парсю ваш сайт, сорри", ну а проблемма скорее всего в "лимитах вк", как показывает практика, в неожиданных ситуациях, есть неожиданные лимиты, полагаю time.delay(30) поможет

Comment: time.sleep(30) ты имел ввиду? Да он чет и не помог,

Comment: мб 30 секунд мало... и вк хочет подождать около часа...  конечно это не реально, можно попробовать костыли с укорочивателем ссылок, мб на них ограничения не распостраняются... или try: download except: sleep(тут ты должен сам зайти на сайт и скачать файл, введя капчу)

Comment: я пошел от обратного и понял, что, скорее всего, именно API вк мне выкидывает такую ошибку, так как полученное с компа изображение я каждый раз загружаю на сервер ВК (при каждом нажатии на кнопку) и отправляю пользователю. Только я пока не могу допереть, как сделать проверку на существование фотографии на сервере

Comment: мб тупо в try обернуть?

Comment: обернул, но теперь он через час крашнулся

Comment: ты повысил работоспособность программы на 50% DDDD можно логи краша?

Comment: на 1200% :D https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/view?file=ed802b96-ed00-4c7c-8bc2-bec1c3df69b8/traceback.txt - лог

Comment: мало\не то в try обернул?

Comment: Может лучше использовать готовые библиотеки, где уже есть нормальные обработчики ошибок и загрузчики фотографий? Например [vkbottle](https://github.com/vkbottle/vkbottle/)

Comment: сейчас пока что нужно использовать vk api, потом перепишу на vkbottle. Вообще проблему уже решил перезапуском скрипта через библу os

Answer (score 0):

столкнулся с той же проблемой, нужно подключать несколько прокси 5-10 и при каждом запросе брать рандомно или по очереди использовать их. Тогда проработает дольше